# How to restrict Particular file type in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

I need to restrict particular file type while uploading into document.
Is there any possible way to restrict?
I know there is no OOTB feature.
Guide me if there any ways ?
Also send me the sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use code to create an ItemAdding event receiver to restrict specific file types when upload to the library.

Reference: [Restrict File Types in SharePoint Document Library Upload using Event Receiver](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/restrict-file-types-in-document-library-event-receiver.html)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in workflow in sharepoint designer?

Comment: You can create a workflow that start automatically when an item is created. and use "delete List Item" action when the file type is equal to relevant type. reference:http://blog.sisq.info/en/2013/03/sharepoint-howto-limit-file-type-in-document-library-to-accept-only-pdf-files/

Comment: i tried that but it deleting all type of files while uploading.

Comment: i think i have done in wrong way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If there is any way in workflow please inform me